# Customizing Twitter Bootstrap From Bootstrap Source folder

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, less

I am developing the RWD web app using twitter bootstrap, i want to do customize the bootstrap fro my needs, for that i downloaded the bootstrap source from [getbootstrap.com](http://getbootstrap.com/) .

I am planning to customize the bootstrap by keeping the bootstrap less files untouched and i want to create my own less files for customiztion as below

```
@import "../bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less";
@import "custom-variables.less";
@import "custom-other.less";
@import "../bootstrap/less/utilities.less";
```

But when i downloaded the bootstrap source, i am seeing so many folders along with the bootstrap LESS folder as below,

**My question is:** what are the files needed for me from bootstrap source folder to include in my web project.

Thanks in advance for any help.

[image]

Comment: If you want less number of files use download bootstrap option instead of source,it gives you compiled version

Comment: @Sid M: I want to customize the bootstrap using my own version of customized LESS, keeping the bootstrap untouched.

Comment: Looks like the LESS files are in, oh I don't know, the `less/` folder. There's also a bunch of bundled documentation you could always read through...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only file you need to import is `bootstrap.less` from `less` folder.
This file itself imports **all the other `.less` files** from that folder (besides `theme.less`, which is used for theming).

I'd suggest importing `bootstrap.less` and using `theme.less` to develop customized solutions.
Reading source of both files above may be beneficial to understanding what is "under the hood".

Remember that although you only import `bootstrap.less`, all the other files must be kept where they are, in order for `bootstrap.less` to be able to import them.

Comment: Rybak: what i understood from your answer is: i need to include the bosststrap.css in my web page(bootstrap.css is output from bootstrap.less), and bootstrap.less is dependent on some LESS files i also need to place it so that bootstrap.less will access,. Do i need to include any JS or font folders?

Comment: that will be it, basically - if you modify any of `.less` files, then compile `bootstrap.less`, the resulting `bootstrap.css` should reflect all your changes.
Whether to include JS depepends on what do you need from bootstrap, if you won't use their JS components (modal etc.) there is no need to do this.

Answer (score 1):

The files you need are in LESS folder. You can create a new file if you don't want to keep bootstrap same with layout.less . And can import that in master. After compilation your changes will be on top of it. You can use any compiler of your choice. e.g. Sublime Text plugin

You can also use just bootstrap.min.css and write your LESS code in a file a compile it to apply your custom changes(remember to import or include in your html file). This way you don't have to keep track of so many LESS file. As in any way your plans are not to change base bootstrap. So you can choose precompiled version and can always replace it when new updates come.

Comment: Thanks For the Help, here you are saying me to use bootstrap.min.css with out less? if so how the compilation of variables which i used in customization.less works?.Please clarify this.

Comment: So as you mentioned, you do not want to make changes in core bootstrap files. Making another less file and using classes of your own or overriding existing in bootstrap variables will work. As you have to compile your less file and include it after bootstrap css which will make it on top priority. In other way use bootstrap.min.css and your less file and compile only that and include in your html.

Comment: by directly including the bootstrap.min.css, i think i lost the chance to change the value of the variable(which are in default in variable.less) and see the result. you will end uo in compilation error, if you change value of bootstrap LESS variables

Comment: Hi, In your question you mentioned you do not want to touch bootstrap less files. That is why i suggested that (you can override the boostrap core style). If you want to change the variables in core bootstrap then you have to use bootstrap less files.